# Spring boot - @getMapping method with a parameter which wasn't passed

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm new to Spring boot so I'm just trying to get my head around a few things. In one of the tutorials I was watching I noticed the instructor did something like this:

```
@GetMapping
public String register(User user) {
    return "register";
}
```

Could someone explain what's going on here in relation to user. Would I be right in thinking that the user is passed to the view "register"?

Also what happens if there's no user passed to this method does it just use a fresh user object. Should autowired be used in that case?

The user class in this case implements UserDetails.

Appologies if my terminology is off as I said I'm new to Spring boot

Comment: 1. Yup! (due to the same rule as 2. and due to the fact it is a get request (and user expected null   ... the framework will populate it for you, sorry harder to prove, but a negative test: delete the default constructor from User!;) 2. You should not/don't need to autowire it, it is picked up by the last rule of [Method Arguments](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-arguments)

Answer (score 1):

Typically, I haven't ran into many cases where you have a `GetMapping` that has a "naked" (non-annotated) object parameter like this.

Usually, arguments to Get method requests are going to be decorated with annotations such as `@RequestParam` or `@PathVariable`. As you have the code now, I immediately think this method wants a `User` object as the `@RequestBody`. But Get requests with bodies is odd in my opinion.

The only exception I can think of is that this is some way to inject the currently logged in user. But in that case, I've only seen this by passing in a Spring Security `Principal` object. I'm not sure a `UserDetail` object works like this but I might be wrong. If this is the case, then what you have is a "special usage" case where Spring is auto-injecting the currently logged in user because it recognizes it as an instance of a `UserDetail`.

Otherwise, I'm not sure where or how Spring is supposed to just put an instance of a `User` object if it's not from an `@RequestBody` or something else. As is, I expect this `User` object to always be null.